# Draw block diagram with pentagons using css and html

Tags: html, css, flowchart

I have a schematic as follows:

[image]

How can I use css and html to draw out such a thing?
I tried some of the ways, but it can not create the border for the triangle, I want the triangles to have borders, and I can set the border to two sides or one edge or all the edges of those triangles. .

Here is the code that I tried with the first pentagon:

```
<style type="text/css">
       div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #4275FF;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 75px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid #4275FF;
  right: -25px;
}
</style>

   <div></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try canvas?

Comment: I do not know that, can you tell me?
I'm not good at font-end

Comment: Its easy. Lot of tutorials are available in youtube. Unfortunately, its not possible to explain in the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: 1px dashed #777;
  position: relative;
}
div.v2 {
  border-right: 0px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  background: inherit;
  border: inherit;
  width: 106px;
  height: 106px;
  top: 21px;
  right: -53px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="v2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the SVG is the best way to create the border for the triangle.
See the code, 'polyline' create a triangle. three 'line' are the border of the triangle, and you can change the color of these lines through the style-stroke-color.

```html
  <svg>
    <polyline points="10,10  50,50  10,90" style="fill:#006600;stroke:#fff;" />
    <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="50" y2="50" style="stroke:#ff0000;" stroke-width="2" />
    <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="10" y2="90" style="stroke:#00ff00;" stroke-width="2" />
    <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="10" y2="90" style="stroke:#0000ff;" stroke-width="2" />
  </svg>
```